# Move Objects With Same Key Value Into An Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to achieve an operation where Ι am not sure where to start with.
 Down below is my initial object:

```
[
  { type: "1", name: "Anthony" },
  {
    type: "1",
    name: "Linus",
  },
  {
    type: "2",
    name: "Sebastin",
  },
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to move the objects which has same type inside an array and have a key value, named title and string type.
I am trying to produce an output equivalent to this and I am not sure where to begin with. Any help will be useful and appreciated. Thanks in advance <3

```
[
  {
    title: "1",
    sub_items: [
      {
        type: "1",
        name: "Anthony",
      },
      {
        type: "1",
        name: "Linus",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "2",
    name: "Sebastin",
  },
];
```

Comment: why does the first object have a title and the second does not?

Comment: because its a common one with both objects having type 1

Comment: why doesn't the second object have a title?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make it with `Array.reduce`

```js
const data = [
  { type: "1", name: "Anthony" },
  {
    type: "1",
    name: "Linus",
  },
  {
    type: "2",
    name: "Sebastin",
  },
];
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr, index, list) => {
  const matchNodes = list.filter((node) => node.type === curr.type);
  if (matchNodes.length > 1) {
    const accNode = acc.find((item) => item.title === curr.type);
    if (accNode) {
      accNode.sub_items.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        title: curr.type,
        sub_items: [curr],
      });
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This works.Sorry my bad i had an issue in when trying it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the input items by type/title and create the desired output:

```js
const input = [{ "type":"1", "name":"Anthony" }, { "type": "1", "name": "Linus" }, { "type":"2", "name":"Sebastin" }]

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { type, name }) => { 
    acc[type] = acc[type] || { title: type, sub_items: [] };
    acc[type].sub_items.push({ type, name });
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: thanks for the response bro <3.Will try it out

Comment: It works but the {
"type":"2",
"name":"Sebastin",
}, object was also being given a title and had a sub item array